# type() in python 2.5 returning error when passing in string

Tags: python

Using Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Sep 30 2008, 15:42:03)
I try to use

```
type(x)
```

and receive the following error when passing in this string '2014-02-06 00:00:00'

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

why does it not return str?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably shadowed the python function `type` with a string by doing the following:

```
>>> type = 'some string'
>>> # Lots of code
>>> x = 'other string'
>>> type(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You can fix this by not using variable names that are also python builtin functions.

---

If you *absolutely* cannot rename your variable to be something other than `type` (`_type` or `type_` will do), you can access the builtin function using the `__builtin__` module

```
>>> type = 'some string'
>>> # Lots of code
>>> x = 'other string'
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

Anyone reading your code will hate you, though.

Comment: oh yea, that s what happened. Good call. thanks.

How can I call the original function. Is there something like a module_xyz.type(x) I can call?

Comment: @chrise `__builtins__.type()`, but you really shouldn't be using `type` as a variable name in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I called type() from within a class. when I do as you suggested, I get 
NameError: global name '_myClass__builtins_' is not defined

How can I do that from within a class?

Comment: sorry, missed that. thanks. Will go for your recommendation and change my variable name. but definitely good to know the work-around